# let CRON send emails through SMTP ( debian squeeze )

Tags: smtp, cron, exim

i would like to send emails whenever a cronjob has completed, i read that this is possible with exim4.

```
in /etc/alias i added the line
myuser: mygmail@gmail.com

in /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf 
i set dc_smarthost='smtp.myserver.ip::25
```

and in  `/etc/exim4/passwd.client` i set

```
smtp.myserver.ip:login@my.domain:mypassword
```

my problem is that i can't see any login at my mailserver, and in the exim logs i saw a few lines with

```
2012-10-13 09:17:01 1TMvy1-0001fp-F2 ** mygmail@gmail.com R=nonlocal: Mailing to remote domains not supported
2012-10-13 09:17:01 1TMvy1-0001fr-JE <= <> R=1TMvy1-0001fp-F2 U=Debian-exim P=local S=17426
```

are there any additional config settings i have to set?

edit : i solved the prev. error by running dpkg-reconfigure, but now i'm facing the following error

```
<root@debian> R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reconfigure your exim4 configuration to be an internet mailer:

```
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

Use the instructions starting in section 2 of the Debian Exim4 readme at http://pkg-exim4.alioth.debian.org/README/README.Debian.html.  Section **2.1.1.1** describes the different types of configuration.

You seem to have it set to "*local delivery only; not on a network*", that needs to be changed to one of the internet style mail servers, pick the one that works best for you.  By your description, it sounds like you want "*mail sent by smarthost; no local mail*".